# Query that shows 'BLOBs stored inline'

Tags: oracle, blob, lob

I need to produce a query that shows a table(table_name, column_name) of where BLOBs are stored inline from user_tables. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine whether a LOB column is stored in-line or out-of-line, you need to take a look at the `IN_ROW` column value of `user_lobs` view (or `[dba]` `[all]` `_lobs` views depending on the privileges granted): `YES` - inline, `NO` - out-of-line:

For instance:

```
select t.table_name
     , t.column_name
     , t.in_row
  from user_lobs t
where table_name = 'BLOB_TABLE'
```

Result:

```
Table Name   Column Name In Row 
--------------------------------
BLOB_TABLE   COL1        YES 
BLOB_TABLE   COL2        YES 
BLOB_TABLE   COL3        YES
```